# Is there a model for both mean and variance?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, heteroscedasticity

Currently we have models where $y^{pred}_{i} \sim N(\beta_1 x_i + \beta_0, \sigma^2)$.

Is it possible to create a model with non-constant variance $y^{pred}_{i} \sim N(\beta_1 x_i + \beta_0, e^{\beta_3 x_i + \beta_2})$?

Comment: Heterogenous variance models exist: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneity_and_heterogeneity_(statistics)

Comment: It is surely possible, there is a specific (R) package for such models, `gamlss`. Peruse the tag [tag:gamlss] for more information!

Comment: @Sycorax Doesn't those models assume constant means?

Comment: How about generalised least squares ? Something like `gls(y ~ x, data = data, weights = varExp(form = ~ x))`

Comment: The ones that don’t assume constant means don’t.

Comment: The Bayesian modeling package `brms` in R has this capability built-in, and unlike the traditional frequentist approach provides exact inference.

Answer (score 4):

The dglm (double generalized linear models) package on CRAN does exactly that. To estimate the model with non-constant variance that you mention in your question, in which $x$ is both a linear predictor for the mean and a log-linear predictor for the variance:

```
library(dglm)
fit <- dglm(y~x, ~x)
summary(fit)
```

The first argument to `dglm` specifies the mean model and the second specifies the variance model.